# Average 3 values loop in 1 column?

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with my code. Basically, I just need to average 3 values in a column and continue that pattern until there are no more values. Can someone please help?

I want to average for example, A1:A3, A4:A6..and so forth until there are no more values. The average result would be in B1:B2.

[image]

```
Sub DLSaverage()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l  As Long, m As Long, myRange As Range

Sheets("DLS Data").Select
i = 2
j = 3
k = 4

Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
    'l = Cells(i, 2).Value
    'm = Cells(k, 2).Value

    'Cells(j, 22).Value = [Average (l : m)]
    i = i + 3
    j = j + 1
    k = k + 3
Set myRange = Range("L" & i & ":L" & k)
Cells(j, 22).Value = Application.Average(myRange)


Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you having problems? You havn't actually asked a question.

Comment: What's wrong? Any errors? Where did you get stuck? How does your sheet look like (screenshot or example data would be nice)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest

```
Option Explicit

Sub testAverage()
    Const Window As Long = 3

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To Target.Rows.Count Step Window
        ws.Cells((iRow \ Window) + 1, "C").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Resize(RowSize:=Window))
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Note that the destination row `ws.Cells((iRow \ Window) + 1, "C").Value` is calculated with a *integer division* `(iRow \ Window) + 1` and is no normal division.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim curRow As Long
    curRow = 1
    Do While Worksheets(1).Cells(curRow, 1) <> ""
        With Worksheets(1)
            .Cells(curRow, 4).Formula = "=AVERAGE(A" & curRow & ":C" & curRow & ")"
            curRow = curRow + 1
        End With
    Loop

End Sub
```

The code above would populate column D with the formula for `=Average(A1:C1)`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, however maybe I didn't explain myself well. I wanted to average say cells A1 to A3, A4 to A6 and have the average in B1:B2.                                                      5 5
5 10
5 15
10 
10 
10 
15 
15 
15

Comment: And you think that "5 5 5 10 5 15 10 10 10 15 15 15" improves the explanation somehow?

Answer (score 0):

this can be done without vba:

Put this in C1 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*3+1):INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*3+3)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetAverages()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, numOutputRows As Long, arr(), i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        arr = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
        Dim outputArray(), rowCounter As Long
        ReDim outputArray(1 To Round(UBound(arr) / 3, 0))
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr) Step 3
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
            outputArray(rowCounter) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(arr(i), arr(i + 1), arr(i + 2))
        Next

        ws.Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(outputArray), 1) = Application.Transpose(outputArray)
    End With
End Sub
```